# tips on how to speed up my server

Tags: performance

I just moved my site from managed vps in florida to unamanaged vps in holland. Ping to my server is now ~30ms, and it was like ~160ms so everything is opening soooo much faster.

What i want to know, my page load time was around 0.18sec but now is aroung 0.6 and 0.7 sec...

I am using cpanel/whm on my server so i have apache, mysql, php and that is all that is used currently by this site. Any quick tips on how to speed up my server?

Comment: There's little information to go on to give you any tips. Are the hardware specs the same? Where are you? Did you compare them at the same time of day?

Comment: Just imagine everything is the same. Again i will point out that this new server is UNMANAGED so everything that is installed now are default stuff that comes with cPanel with default settings. That is my problem, i neeed to tweek my server... Like i said to John Gardeniers "What i need is answers like ErikA gave me, aka what apache modules to install, what php accelerator/cache software to install and stuff like that."...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your next venture in getting more performance out of your app will most likely need to be some sort of caching layer. If you're using a pre-built CMS, check to see if it already has a caching function you can turn on. If not, you'll need to look into something like [APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC), a PHP accelerator/cache or perhaps [memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/), a more general-purpose memory object caching system.

Comment: Like i said, everything was just moved to this new server. So the only difference is server and its setup. Thanks for those links, will try them when i wake up. :)

Comment: Well, like you said, it's a different server/setup. The host likely has different hardware, and the providers likely use different virtualization tech. Perhaps the host server you're on now is more highly loaded than the old server. Any of these could cause the slower performance.

Also - one thing to keep in mind, latency != bandwidth. Even though your ping times are faster doesn't *necessarily* mean that bandwidth is higher between you and your server.

Comment: What i meant is that there is nothing in my software which could improve this load time. ;) Because the only difference is server, software is the same.

Comment: Doesn't mean the the software doesn't have room for improvement.

Comment: Well i dont care about software impovment atm, all i need now is to see how to make my server work good.

Answer (score 0):

As dlamblin commented, there is nowhere near enough detail in your question. At the very least you need to give us the specs for each server. For all we know one is a super computer and the other is a 486.

Having said that, I really doubt there is anything you can do about the server performance, so concentrate on the software instead. Or move to a better server, because ping time indicates network speed, not server speed.

Comment: You are missing the point, this new server is unmanaged, so the only things that are installed are default stuff with default settings. What i need is answers like ErikA gave me, aka what apache modules to install, what php accelerator/cache software to install and stuff like that.

Comment: No, you're missing the point. Be specific about what you are asking and give enough information to allow people to provide answers. Your question (you might want to read it yourself) is about speeding up your server. You did NOT ask about performance tuning an application.

Comment: Well maybe i wrote it wrong because im a newbie about all this. When i say "speed up my server" i mean "fine tune apache/php/etc"... Sorry for that. :(